# Does the VM under the NAT network can contact the dedicated servers?

Tags: nat, vmware

I have bellow snapshot's network configration:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

in the Dedicated Control Server(`172.18.1.249`) there is a VMware VM1 with ip `172.18.1.247`, and it use the NAT network(gateway is `172.18.1.248`).

I want to use the VM1 for controlling all the Dedicated Servers(in the right side).

now I can ping the `172.18.1.247`, `172.18.1.248`, `172.18.1.1`, `172.18.1.2`, `172.18.1.3` from Dedicated Control Server(`172.18.1.249`).
and the right side servers(`172.18.1.1-3`) can ping `172.18.1.249`, can not ping `172.18.1.247-248`.

Because the VM1 is not a conventional operating system, it is a NOC-PS system, so I can not test the ping from VM1, but I test the tool to control the right side server get fail.

My question is, is the VM1 can contact the right side servers? or ping them? 
and if not, how can I realize my requirement?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configuration are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can ping the 172.18.1.247, 172.18.1.248, 172.18.1.1, 172.18.1.2, 172.18.1.3 from Dedicated Control Server(172.18.1.249). and the right side servers(172.18.1.1-3) can ping 172.18.1.249, can not ping 172.18.1.247-248.

This is because you use source NAT. This translates the source address 172.18.1.247 to 172.18.1.248 and makes the former invisible and only work one-way. There's no way you can ping from right (outside) to left (inside).

For a node from outside the NAT to connect to the inside you'd need port forwarding aka destination NAT from 172.18.1.248 to 172.18.1.247.

Instead of NAT you should consider bridging the vNICs to the physical network. This makes the vNIC IPs visible to the physical servers.